# Randomly generate numbers based on given probabilities R

Tags: r, random

I need help creating a for loop to fill in a 5X5 table using R. Each row will be one observation without replacement. The number range is 1:75, and respectively I have probabilities for each of these numbers. So how would I go about creating a random number generating code that takes into account the specific probability for each number?

Comment: Are you playing BINGO? Look at the `?sample` help page. You can specify weights/probabilities for each number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample data:

```
A <- seq_len(75)
B <- rpois(75, 3)
B <- B / sum(B)
```

So now `B` is a probability vector for each element in `A`.

To pull 25 samples, simply use `sample(A, size = 25, replace = FALSE, prob = B)`. Fill the matrix as usual `MAT <- matrix(sample(A, size = 25, replace = FALSE, prob = B), nrow = 5)`.